# "$.______ is not a function" error. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to add an image rotator to my site but for some reason firebug tells me the function I need to call to start the rotator isn't defined. My jQuery file is loading just fine and the image rotator script is loading so I'm not sure what is wrong. The site is [heritage.newcoastmedia.com](http://heritage.newcoastmedia.com) but I'll go ahead and post the script:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.featureList = function(options) {
        var tabs    = $(this);
        var output  = $(options.output);

        new jQuery.featureList(tabs, output, options);

        return this;    
    };

    $.featureList = function(tabs, output, options) {
        function slide(nr) {
            if (typeof nr == "undefined") {
                nr = visible_item + 1;
                nr = nr >= total_items ? 0 : nr;
            }

            tabs.removeClass('current').filter(":eq(" + nr + ")").addClass('current');

            output.stop(true, true).filter(":visible").fadeOut();
            output.filter(":eq(" + nr + ")").fadeIn(function() {
                visible_item = nr;  
            });
        }

        var options         = options || {}; 
        var total_items     = tabs.length;
        var visible_item    = options.start_item || 0;

        options.pause_on_hover      = options.pause_on_hover        || true;
        options.transition_interval = options.transition_interval   || 5000;

        output.hide().eq( visible_item ).show();
        tabs.eq( visible_item ).addClass('current');

        tabs.click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
                return false;   
            }

            slide( tabs.index( this) );
        });

        if (options.transition_interval > 0) {
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                slide();
            }, options.transition_interval);

            if (options.pause_on_hover) {
                tabs.mouseenter(function() {
                    clearInterval( timer );

                }).mouseleave(function() {
                    clearInterval( timer );
                    timer = setInterval(function () {
                        slide();
                    }, options.transition_interval);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And here is the script to start the image rotator:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.featureList(
            $("#tabs li a"),
            $("#output li"), {
                start_item  :   1
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `;(function($) {`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Typo or not, it doesn't matter - it just creates an empty statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code creates an anonymous function, but doesn't call it.

You need to call the function by adding `(jQuery)` at the end.

Comment: This is the answer. - a great tool for finding issues like this (semantically correct jQuery, but with things like hanging statements instead of assignments) is JSLint: http://www.jslint.com/  - it parses and analyzes your code for logical errors and bad programming practices.

Comment: But when I add (jQuery) to the end of the plugin I get another error saying jQuery is not defined 
})(jQuery);

Comment: @user: You need to run your script after including jQuery, not before.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `$.featureList(`

See Chrome error: [image]

The plugin needs to applied to an object

Comment: Uh? What do you mean by that? *The plugin needs to applied to an object*

Comment: Actually, you can.  Read his plugin.

Comment: No. He defines $.featureList in his code. The problem is that the code that defines the function never actually gets executed (he defines the closure, but never executes it).

Answer (score 0):

You've just slightly missed out on the right syntax for creating a plugin.  What you  really want is:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.featureList = function() { // etc; }
   $.featureList = function() { // yet more etc; }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Correct example, but an explanation of *why* would be helpful. Without the (jQuery) at the end, he's only defined a closure/function - but never actually executes the code inside.